# Rails: Frozen Error when trying to run rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running a rails application and when it now shows the below error in console and web application is not loading.

> FrozenError (can't modify frozen fatal):

Please help as I don't even understand what this is. Will provide any further code details if mentioned.

Comment: Are you using ruby version `2.5.0` ?

Comment: we are using ruby '2.5.3'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason. I will explain here the way which I found the solution for the issue so that it may help others who encounter the same error.

I saw the FrozenError class documentation and found that this was introduced in ruby 2.5.x and later. This is the document 
[FrozenError Doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/FrozenError.html) . I just first upgraded ruby version to latest 2.6.x but this didn't solve the issue.

**Fix:**

- Downgraded the ruby version below 2.5.x to 2.4.x.
- Now in 2.4.x, this FrozenError class does not exist.
- I could now see the real error that caused the issue. It was a
  **SystemStackError**.
- It was caused due a gem in project (wicked_pdf).
- Removing the gem solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when upgrading a Rails app from 4.2.10 to 5.0. The error only happened with wicked_pdf 2.0.1, a downgrade to wicked_pdf 1.4.0 also made the trick.

Comment: I was struggling for hours. until I found your recommendation. This still happens on Rails 6 :@

Comment: this helped me too, thanks @pab

Answer (score 1):

For me, it occurred when I tried to find `resource.class` after running `build_resource`,

To solve this I removed .class from the `resource` object

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still struggling with that error, perhaps could be the name of you file

Example:

```rb
# filename my_api_class.rb -> bad should be my_a_p_i_class.rb

class MyAPIClass
```

to

```rb
# filename my_api_class.rb

class MyApiClass
```

Comment: would you share more details about why it is so?

Comment: @AbhijithRavindran this is due to the way that Rails manages autoloading of classes, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#project-structure

In this case you can see the difference in behavior between `"my_api_class".camelize` and `"my_a_p_i_class".camelize`